# How to fix this error in spring-batch? jobReposiroty must be set

Tags: spring-batch

Im new to Springbatch and have a very simple code to Create a SpringBatch POC (without springboot) move data from MySql to CSV and it shows me this error:

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory
> method 'job' threw exception with message:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JobRepository must be set

I tried to google it but can't find any working example.
can someone plz explains what im missing ?

And I want to use a different datasrouce for jobRepository than the one Im batching from

My main class:

```
import com.techtalk.debu.batch.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
public class LoadController {

    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .generateUniqueName(false).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("1234567890");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource batchDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(batchDataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String e []) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LoadController.class);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();


        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(context.getBean(Job.class), jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Job Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(5, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())           
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job")
                .start(step(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> itemReader() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .sql(sql)
                .beanRowMapper(Employee.class)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }



}
```

My Pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.techtalk.debu</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Batch-CSV-to-DB-Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-batch-CSV-To_DB-Write-Example-For-Beginners</name>
    <description>Demo project for Beginners to understand Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The Employee class

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_analytics_table")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone_number;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `jobRepository` in the `JobBuilder`:

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
  return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
      .start(step(jobRepository, transactionManager))
      .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
public class LoadController{

    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .generateUniqueName(false).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.example.demo"});
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());

        return em;
    }

    private final Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("root");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("root-password");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource batchDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(batchDataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String e []) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LoadController.class);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();


        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(context.getBean(Job.class), jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Job Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(5, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(step(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> itemReader() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .sql(sql)
                .beanRowMapper(Employee.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did. But still nothing changed

Comment: I have updated my first comment with an update for the **LoadController** Class

Comment: Check the full working code in this repo: https://github.com/saadjareer/spring-batch-processing-demo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).